# Swift 3: Buttons not working on controller added as subview

Tags: ios, swift, controller, addsubview

I recently upgraded to Xcode 8.0/Swift 3.

I'm adding a controller to pick images as a subview to another controller, and for some reason the buttons on the controller added as a subview won't work. This was no problem before.

Here's the code:

```
let pickerController = DKImagePickerController()


 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pickerController.defaultSelectedAssets = self.assets

    pickerController.didSelectAssets = { (assets: [DKAsset]) in
        print("didSelectAssets")
    }

    self.addChildViewController(pickerController)
    self.view.addSubview(pickerController.view)
    pickerController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

Any ideas? All the answers I find suggest this should work :(

The callback (didSelectAssets) works find if I just present the pickerController using

```
self.present(pickerController, animated: true) {}
```

Comment: Present method as you know presents VC modally. I have impression that there is some extra view around your button.

Comment: I hope that isUserInteractionEnabled is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DKImagePickerController` appears to be designed only for *presenting* as a view controller, not for adding as a childVC and subview to your current view. So, because you didn't *present* it, it fails to make the callback.

If that's how you want to display it, you'll need to make some edits to `DKImagePickerController` itself.

A quick test of changing the `done()` func in `DKImagePickerController.swift` to this:

```
open func done() {

    if self.presentingViewController == nil {
        self.didSelectAssets?(self.selectedAssets)
    }
    else
    {

        self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            self.didSelectAssets?(self.selectedAssets)
        })

    }
}
```

will result in your callback func being called:

```
pickerController.didSelectAssets = { (assets: [DKAsset]) in
    print("didSelectAssets")
}
```

From there, however, you'll have to do your own coding for removing the subview, handling the selections, etc. You may also need to modify some other functions inside `DKImagePickerController` - I just did a quick test to get the callback working.

Comment: Works perfectly. I didn't think about that :) Thank you so much for looking into it so deeply!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the methods ViewWillAppear() or viewDidAppear() instead of viewDidLoad()

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    pickerController.defaultSelectedAssets = self.assets

    pickerController.didSelectAssets = { (assets: [DKAsset]) in
        print("didSelectAssets")
    }

    self.addChildViewController(pickerController)
    self.view.addSubview(pickerController.view)
    pickerController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should check your picker frame. Try adding it **clipToBounds = true** to check if the entire view is displayed.